# Change all article text format to basic html

Tags: 8, migrations

I installed Drupal 8 on my site and used migrate to migrate my old site Drupal 6 to Drupal 8.

The error message pop out.

[image]

But when total articles have been all imported to new site Drupal 8.

The content of the article is not displaying. Only title of article shown.

I checked the article, there is content there.

It needs to be change from text format FULL HTML to BASIC HTML to make it appear on the site.

[image]

I have more than 20,000 articles.
How do I do change it for all?

Is it adding the script here and press "Format"?
[image]

[image]

Comment: The `db_update` is for use in Drupal, answer updated with raw SQL option too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you might just need to add/configure the `full_html` text format, you can update the text format for all body fields to `basic_html` via a DB query ( and clear cache )

```
db_update('node__body')
  ->fields(array('body_format' => 'basic_html'))
  ->condition('bundle', 'article')
  ->execute();

db_update('node_revision__body')
  ->fields(array('body_format' => 'basic_html'))
  ->condition('bundle', 'article')
  ->execute();
```

The raw SQL equivalent (e.g for PHPMyAdmin) is:

```
UPDATE node__body set body_format = 'basic_html' where bundle = 'article';
UPDATE node_revision__body set body_format = 'basic_html' where bundle = 'article';
```

Backup your database *first*

Comment: Do you mean add the script here http://i.stack.imgur.com/t44pv.jpg

Comment: @user73963 the code is for Drupal usage. Answer updated with raw SQL option

Comment: it show me this  # MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows) and the article format is still full html.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/qmS79.jpg
@David Thomas

Comment: @user73963 the above assumes you're matching only the 'article' content type. make sure you clear cache at admin > config > performance > clear cache ( /admin/config/development/performance )